# Simple absolute import causing 'Cannot find module' error

Tags: typescript

I have reproduced this in the little project [here](https://github.com/github-account-because-they-want-it/ts-play).

So I have a `main.ts` that looks like:

```
import hello from "dm/lib/helper"

hello("Jeff")
```

and `helper.ts` in `src/lib/herlper.ts` that looks like:

```
export default function hello(name: string) {
    console.log(`Hello ${name}`)
}
```

Pretty simple. Now on to `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
        "dm/*": [
            "./src/*"
        ],
    },
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

The compile/transpile works fine and some Javascript is spewed out. Running `main.js` using `npm start` gives an error like:

```
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'dm/lib/helper'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
```

I didn't expect TypeScript to include `dm/` I'm using to refer to the project root in the final JS. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well according to [this closed issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15479) it's not possible to use absolute imports without external tools in TypeScript, mainly because it won't rewrite your imports in the emitted JavaScript.

In frontend projects you can have **webpack** resolve these imports but since I'm doing a nodejs/electron project I still don't have webpack setup here.

It's also intriguing that [VSCode](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/editor/editor.main.ts) manages to use absolute imports in TypeScript but they are also using webpack but I don't know how they do achieve that effect just yet. If you know how do they pull that off feel free to answer this question.

**UPDATE**

So I managed to use **webpack** to enable absolute imports in my TypeScript/nodejs project. This is by no means the only way to do it but it works.

I updated my [project code here](https://github.com/github-account-because-they-want-it/ts-play). Here are some highlights:

Install these:

`npm install --save-dev webpack webpack-cli webpack-node-externals ts-loader`

Add webpack config in `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require("path")
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals")

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    target: "node",
    entry: {
        app: ["./src/main.ts"]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: "ts-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            dm: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/")
        },
        extensions: [".ts", ".js"]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/"),
        filename: "main.js"
    },
    externals: [nodeExternals()]
}
```

Build and run the project:

`npm run build && npm start`

Comment: In addition to this, I've had to use the allowlist option in node-externals (https://github.com/liady/webpack-node-externals#optionsallowlist-), which allowed me to include some referenced modules from my monorepo in the build.

Answer (score 0):

Your project structure is:

```
main.ts
-- lib
   helper.ts
```

So your import ought to be:

```
import hello from './lib/helper';
```

Once you type `./` your IDE or text editor should step in and help you get the path right, i.e. Visual Studio Code:

[image: VS Code Auto Completion]

As an aside, module resolution in Node means you need to put `./` in your path to load the relative module. You can read mode in the [Node Modules docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html). You want to hit rule (3) in the below list.

```
require(X) from module at path Y
1. If X is a core module,
   a. return the core module
   b. STOP
2. If X begins with '/'
   a. set Y to be the filesystem root
3. If X begins with './' or '/' or '../'
   a. LOAD_AS_FILE(Y + X)
   b. LOAD_AS_DIRECTORY(Y + X)
4. LOAD_NODE_MODULES(X, dirname(Y))
5. THROW "not found"
```

Comment: thank you @Fenton for trying to help. My actual project code is kinda bigger so I need an easy way to refer to the project root while importing (the `dm` or whatever) wihtout needing to do `../../../helper` bloat. If you look at [this file from VSCode source](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/editor/editor.all.ts) they are using the same convention to avoid relative imports. Can you help me achieve that here?

Comment: In that case you could use option (2) to start the path from root, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is still an issue to this day, I thought I'd point out that there's a much simpler npm package called [tscpaths](https://github.com/joonhocho/tscpaths) as alternative to using webpack that translates your built JS import paths in a very no-frills way. I actually discovered it listed as an alternative to [resolve-tspaths](https://www.npmjs.com/package/resolve-tspaths) that does something similar but seems to require a nonstandard path prefix, which I didn't like. The latter is more feature rich though, which I didn't need but may be useful to some.

Usage is really easy, just install with

```
npm i -D tscpaths
```

and run with

```
npx tscpaths -p tsconfig.json -s src -o dist
```

This can of course be added to your `package.json` at the end of your build script.

```
{

  ...

  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc; tscpaths -p tsconfig.json -s src -o dist"
  }
}
```